# After I use dataset,concatenate, dataset.map only act on original data

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

As the title says, I concatenate two dataset and use map function to change value's position and rescale value. Before I use map, all Tensor's shape are
matched, but after using map function, and use for loop iterate dataset to print index, and iteration's break point is on two dataset joint.

I run into this problem in Colab using GPU,
and use Python 3.6, tensorflow-gpu 2.0.0b1

```py
dataset_crop = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(img_resize_and_crop_genr, (tf.float32, tf.float32),((7,), (48,48,1)))
dataset = dataset.concatenate(dataset_crop)
dataset = dataset.map(lambda label, img_raw: (tf.cast(img_raw, tf.float32)/float(255), label))
for i,(label, img) in enumerate(dataset):
  print(i)
```

By the way, dataset's total row has 19984 before concatenating 

What the concatenate hell..

```
...
19982
19983
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-36305ee0e8ef> in <module>()
----> 1 for i,(label, img) in enumerate(dataset):
      2   print(i)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

InvalidArgumentError: ValueError: Tensor's shape (7,) is not compatible with supplied shape [48, 48, 1]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 209, in __call__
    ret = func(*args)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 525, in generator_py_func
    values = next(generator_state.get_iterator(iterator_id))

  File "<ipython-input-25-196a9ac04fc0>", line 5, in img_resize_and_crop_genr
    img.set_shape([side_len, side_len,1])

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 981, in set_shape
    (self.shape, shape))

ValueError: Tensor's shape (7,) is not compatible with supplied shape [48, 48, 1]


     [[{{node PyFunc}}]] [Op:IteratorGetNextSync]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `from_generator` function. When you are passing the `output_shapes` parameter, a strict checking is done to see whether the output shape is exactly the same shape being generated or not. In your case, you are getting a `ValueError` stating that it is expecting (48, 48, 1) but (7,) shape got generated.

A similar error can be generated using the following code:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((np.zeros(19984, dtype=np.float32), np.ones(19984, dtype=np.float32)))

def img_resize_and_crop_genr():
    yield np.zeros((7,)), np.ones((48, 48, 1))

dataset_crop = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(img_resize_and_crop_genr, (tf.float32, tf.float32),((48,48,1), (7,)))
dataset = dataset.concatenate(dataset_crop)
dataset = dataset.map(lambda label, img_raw: (tf.cast(img_raw, tf.float32)/float(255), label))
for i,(label, img) in enumerate(dataset):
  print(i)
```

Output:

```
ValueError: `generator` yielded an element of shape (7,) where an element of shape (48, 48, 1) was expected.
```

I believe you have interchanged your `output_shapes`. If that is the case, you can make the correction as:

```
dataset_crop = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(img_resize_and_crop_genr, 
                                              (tf.float32, tf.float32),((7,), (48,48,1)))
```

Also, `output_shapes` is an optional parameter. You can avoid the problem whole together by not passing the parameter as shown below:

```
dataset_crop = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(img_resize_and_crop_genr, 
                                              (tf.float32, tf.float32))
```

Comment: Yeh, two dataset are same shape before concatenated.But I want to concatenate together to change value position just like (y,x) -> (x,y) using dataset's map function.

Comment: By the way, if using from_generator to concatenate dataset, it work.In other words,concatenated object is opposite, it work.What the concatenate hell..